# Show image returned as binary data from API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to display an image in angular which is received back from a Node API in response to a GET request. The Node model is:

```
    var stream = canvas.pngStream();

    stream.on('data', function(chunk){
        array.push(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function(){
      callback(Buffer.concat(array));
    });
```

And the router and callback are:

```
router.get('/canvas', function(req, res) {

    var callback = function(img){

        console.log('img is ');
        console.log(img);

         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
         res.end(img, 'binary');
    };

    canvas.getCanvas(callback);   
});
```

I'm successfully receiving the data back in the browser. In angular, my template looks like:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64, {{avatarImage}}"/>
```

And controller is:

```
function getFile () {
    // body...

    FilesService.getCanvas($stateParams.id)
    .success(function(data){

        console.log('result! and data is ');
        console.log(data);

        $scope.avatarImage = data;

    })
    .error(function(err){
        console.log('err is ');
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Angular is receiving the image because in console i see:

```
result! and data is 
�PNG
IHDR��<q�bKGD��������IDATx����Ue���²n���.�(H�h���3LSq��엥       �eM���3��4Ō�X:�HkV3mG'��I%+���$�b�����B��|
```

However I just see a broken image icon in the browser. Angular then makes another GET request to :

```
data:image/png;base64, %EF%BF%BDPNG%1A%00%00%00IHDR%00%00%00%EF....
```

Any ideas how I can show an image returned as binary?

Comment: Have you tried just `res.end(img)` (without the 'binary' arg)? Also, since that callback doesn't handle errors, I wonder if they might be happening silently?

Comment: yep tried that, will try listen for errors but can see data is getting to browser...

Comment: Just guessing now. What about adding a length header? `'content-length': img.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a data url that is expecting base64-encoded data, but you're responding back with the raw binary data instead.

Try this:

```
res.end(img.toString('base64'));
```

Instead of this:

```
res.end(img, 'binary');
```

Also you may need to remove the space after the comma and before `{{avatarImage}}` in your img tag.